# Тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

"И эта странная фраза() "Собака — друг человека"..."
После слова "фраза" тут нужно тире или двоеточие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы поставил тире, ибо цитата здесь является приложением, носящим пояснительный характер: фраза (а именно) какая?

Comment: Даже и в этом случае тире. В случае если два тире подряд, одно тире заменяется на двоеточие. Текст воспринимается легче.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно двоеточие. Вторая часть предложения раскрывает смысл первой.